# How can I set autocomplete attribute in elgg login form?

Tags: plugins, autocomplete, elgg

I want to set autocomplete attribute off in elgg login form in my plugin(specially for username).How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Read about views overriding: http://learn.elgg.org/en/1.11/guides/views.html

Login form is defined by the view `forms/login`. You can just override it with custom version of the view where you'd change

```
echo elgg_view('input/text', array(
    'name' => 'username',
    'autofocus' => true,
));
```

to include `'autocomplete' => 'on'`